# Bold substrings of search results depending on searchquery

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to achieve a bolding part of the search result depending on the user's input but with the original spelling.
I want to avoid dots, multiple spaces, dashes, and make it case insensitive.

For example, I have a simple search result: `Al. Jana`.

I'm trying to bold searched part, so:

When user types `al`, I want to show -> **Al**. Jana

`Al` -> **Al**. Jana

`AL` -> **Al**. Jana

`al jana` -> **Al. Jana**

`jana` -> Al. **Jana**

`Al. Jana` -> **Al. Jana**

Or if we have a search result `Al. Jana Something - More` and the user types `something more` it should return: Al. Jana **Something - More**.

So far I wrote this code:

```
function modify(result, query) {
    let re = new RegExp(query, 'ig');
    return result.replace(/- /g, "").replace(/\./g, "").replace(re, '<b>' + query + '</b>'); //replacing "- " as dash is always surrounded with spaces so it trims one unnecessary space; is there a better way to make "inside-trim"?
}

let bolded = modify("Al. Jana", "al jana");
console.log(bolded);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ayb8Lj4r/

But it isn't what I want to achieve. Maybe I should heavily use `.indexOf`? I'm not sure.

Comment: If your query is `al jana` and the text is `Al. Jana Something - More`, I understand you want to get `<b>Al. Jana</b> Something - More`, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew right

Comment: Why are you removing the period and the hyphen in your code?

Comment: When search result is ```Al. Jana Something - More``` and query is ```something more``` I want it to return ```Al. Jana <b>Something - More</b>```.

Comment: You should put that in your question

Comment: You're right, I've updated question. Sorry.

Comment: Use https://jsfiddle.net/djpe4fkg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `[-\s.]*` pattern in between all individual characters of the search query. This will allow any amount of spaces, `-` or `.` chars between the characters. If you want to allow any non-word chars you may use `\W*` instead.

Besides, you should escape all the special characters, otherwise, if the query contains a char like `(` or `+`, the results won't be as expected.

Here is the fixed snippet:

```js
function modify(result, query) {
  var re = new RegExp(query.split("").map(function(x) { 
      return x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'); 
  }).join("[-\\s.]*"), 'ig');
  return result.replace(re, '<b>$&</b>');
}

var bolded = modify("Al. Jana Something - More", "al jana");
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = bolded;
```

```html
<div id="result"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

To get the result you're looking for you can utilize capture groups along with your variable.

```
let re = new RegExp('(' + query + ')', 'ig');
```

This allows you to use `$1` within your second parameter of the `replace`function to point to the matched text as it is case-wise within your original string.

```
return result.replace(/- /g, "")
   .replace(/\./g, "")
   .replace(re, '<b>$1</b>');
```

Finally to replace `al jana` with `al. jana` we can do an additional replace.

```
query = query.replace(/(al) (jana)/ig, "$1. $2");
```

And delete your period replacement

```
       .replace(/\./g, "")
```

And since we *want* hyphens too, based on your comments, we can remove that line as well

```
      .replace(/- /g, "")
```

And we're left with:

```
function modify(result, query) {
  query = query.replace(/(al) (jana)/ig, "$1. $2");
    let re = new RegExp('(' + query + ')', 'ig');
    return result.replace(re, '<b>$1</b>');
}
```

---

### Example

```js
function modify(result, query) {
  query = query.replace(/(al) (jana)/ig, "$1. $2");
 let re = new RegExp('(' + query + ')', 'ig');
 return result.replace(re, '<b>$1</b>');
}

let bolded = modify("Al. Jana Something - More", "al jana");
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = bolded;
```

```html
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: Yay! It works! But you placed specific words in brackets, and also added dot in ```$1. $2``` in specific place. What if the ```query``` parameter is different? How to make it work for every ```query``` with dots and dashes?

Comment: @Marcin What do you mean? If you want other phrases to add punctuation you need to program them in otherwise it won't know where to put the punctuation.